# CSS animation to make an <h1> element translate 3px higher when I hover over it

Tags: css, button, hover, transform, translate

I am trying to create a button with an  element. I am trying to give this button a small behavior, by making it rise 3px when I hover over it.

I have tried putting the **transform:translateY(-3px);** as a @keyframes animation (which is how it is here in the snippet) and I have also tried simply putting the **transform:translateY(-3px);** simply under the header-main:hover selector. Both ways seem to translate the button way off what it would supposed to be. It seems to go bottom-right instead.

Keep in mind, I am very new to coding, as this is my 2nd month coding,

Thank you!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Tag Selectors*/
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


header {
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #00000045);
}

/*Class Selectors*/
.header-main {
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.header-main:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: jumpUp 0.2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes jumpUp {
50% {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test for btn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>

        <h1 class="header-main">Start free trial</h1>
      
        </header>






  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`translateY` is redoing the whole transformation (removing `translateX and the original translateY). Instead, use the original translation and subtract 3px from the y:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Tag Selectors*/
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


header {
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #00000045);
}

/*Class Selectors*/
.header-main {
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.header-main:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: jumpUp 0.2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes jumpUp {
50% {
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% - 3px));
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test for btn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>

        <h1 class="header-main">Start free trial</h1>
      
        </header>






  </body>
</html>
```

So inside `keyframes`:

```
transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% - 3px));
```